# 1 to 5 of the same groups in REGEX

Tags: regex

For a string such as:

ab**zyx**cab**kmqf**cmkcde

Notice that there are string patterns between `ab` and `c` in bold.  To capture the first string pattern:

`ab([a-z]{3,5})c`

Is it possible to match both of the groups from the sample string? Actually, there should be 1 to 5 groups.

*Note: python style regex.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can verify that a given string conforms to the 1-5 repetitions of ab([a-z]{3,5})c using this regex

```
(?:ab([a-z]{3,5})c){1,5}
```

or this one if there are characters expected between the groups

```
(?:ab([a-z]{3,5})c.*?){1,5}
```

You will only be able to extract the last matching group from that string however, not any of the previous ones.  to get a previous one you need to use hsz's approach

Answer (score 1):

Just match all results - i.e. with `g` flag:

```
/ab([a-z]{3,5})c/g
```

or some method like in Python:

```
re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
```

Comment: That works, but it requires more logic from programming side to verify that there are 1 to 5 groups.  If there are more groups, then I want them to not be matched.  Maybe it is not possible?

Comment: @user1135541 I'm not familiar with Python, specifically, but that should be possible with something like this: `(?:ab([a-z]{3,5})c.*?){1,5}`

Comment: it works for verifying the whole string fits the pattern, but it won't extract all of the capture groups (I don't think this is actually possible, though)